# Create a pandas series of negative number bins

Tags: python, pandas

I want to create a pandas series of negative numbered bins for deceleration values.

```
df['data_bin'] = pd.cut(df['data'], [0,-0.98,-1.96,-2.94,-3.92,-12.00],
                        labels=['0,-0.98','-0.98,-1.96','-1.96,-2.94',
                                '-2.94,-3.92','-3.92,-12.00'])
```

I'm getting the following error:

> ValueError: bins must increase monotonically.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you need reversing inputs:

```
data = pd.DataFrame({'acceleration':[-11,-1,-2,-4]})

bins = [-12.00,-3.92,-2.94,-1.96,-0.98, 0]
labels = ['-3.92,-12.00', '-2.94,-3.92','-1.96,-2.94','-0.98,-1.96','0,-0.98']

data['decceleration_bin'] = pd.cut(data['acceleration'], bins=bins, labels=labels)
print (data)
   acceleration decceleration_bin
0           -11      -3.92,-12.00
1            -1       -0.98,-1.96
2            -2       -1.96,-2.94
3            -4      -3.92,-12.00
```

You can also create labels dynamically:

```
data = pd.DataFrame({'acceleration':[-11,-1,-2,-4]})

bins = [-12.00,-3.92,-2.94,-1.96,-0.98, 0]
labels = [f'{j},{i}' for i, j in zip(bins[:-1], bins[1:])] 
print (labels)
['-3.92,-12.00', '-2.94,-3.92', '-1.96,-2.94', '-0.98,-1.96', '0,-0.98']

data['decceleration_bin'] = pd.cut(data['acceleration'], bins=bins, labels=labels)
print (data)
   acceleration decceleration_bin
0           -11      -3.92,-12.00
1            -1       -0.98,-1.96
2            -2       -1.96,-2.94
3            -4      -3.92,-12.00
```

Answer (score 0):

The error explains that bins must increase [monotonically](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monotonic_function). So you can just reverse your inputs to satisfy this condition:

```
B = [0, -0.98, -1.96, -2.94, -3.92, 12.00]
L = ['0,-0.98', '-0.98,-1.96', '-1.96,-2.94', '-2.94,-3.92', '-3.92,-12.00']

df['data_bin'] = pd.cut(df['data'], bins=B[::-1], labels=L[::-1])
```